Use JWT token with FactoryBoy's tests and FastAPI
I've some problems to find examples to use FactoryBoy (with FastAPI)  with JWT token.
My integration fastapi+jwt is working. But, testing... I'm confused.
Here's my code :
def fake_oauth2_token():
    client_token = TestClient(app)
    response = client_token.post(
        "api/auth/login/",
        data={
            "grant_type": "password",
            "username": "me",
            "password": "mypass",
            "scope": "",
            "client_id": "",
            "client_secret": "",
        },
    )
    token = json.loads(response.content)
    return token["access_token"] if token else {}

def test_get_flower():
    """ """
    flower = FlowerFactory()
    mock_session = MagicMock()
    mock_session.query.return_value.all.return_value = [flower]
    app.dependency_overrides[oauth2_scheme] = lambda: fake_oauth2_token()
    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = lambda: mock_session
    client = TestClient(app)

    response = client.get("api/flower/")
    assert response.status_code == 200

I get this error :

TypeError: hash must be unicode or bytes, not unittest.mock.MagicMock

And, if I remove this lines :
app.dependency_overrides[oauth2_scheme] = lambda: fake_oauth2_token()

then I get a 401 error: it's fine, authentication issue.
How can I inject my token in headers please?

I think you got mixed up in what you are want to achieve. You are overrwriting dependency oauth2_scheme with fake_oauth2_token which should go and grab token. But I don't see where you create a user with test credentials.
It would probably be better if you first change fake_oauth2_token to a fixture that generates a token for a user in the database. I'll try to show you an approximate example of how I would do it.
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def user(db):
    #create a user or in the fake database 
    # or mock response in database 
    # I persoally prefer to create data in database
    user = UserFactory.build()
    db.add(user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(user)
    return user 

@pytest.fixture
def client(db):
   app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = lambda: mock_session

   client = TestClient(app)

   yield client


def test_get_flower(client, user):
    flower = FlowerFactory()
    mock_session.query.return_value.all.return_value = [flower]

    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = lambda: mock_session

    client = TestClient(app)

    # probably you generate a token based on user data 
    # so you can invoke it here
    auth_token = generate_token(some_user_data=user.some_field)

    headers={
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {auth_token}',
    }

    response = client.get("api/flower/", headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 200

This probably won't just that but it should give you steps you need to take.  Generate a user, a token before a test and the rest of the app workflow should go as expected.
I have an examples where I work with a database in tests. I will share you links as they might be also help you:

https://github.com/ViAchKoN/dataclass-sqlalchemy-mixins/blob/master/tests/conftest.py
https://github.com/ViAchKoN/fastapi-project-blueprint/blob/master/tests/conftest.py


thanks, I'll try this and I tell you :)
